# Parsing Xml via XPath gives error

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I have a very simple xml string that I loaded using XmlDocument class. Now I am trying to read it via XPath query and I get this error,

"Expression must evaluate to a node-set."

Here is my Xml,

```
<RF_SearchTermBanners>
   <ImageName>3pc-leather-set.jpg</ImageName>
</RF_SearchTermBanners>
```

Here is my C# code,

```
protected void BindSearchBanner(string ImageUrl)
{
    //Parse Xml string containing Image name
    System.Xml.XmlDocument xmlDoc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
    xmlDoc.LoadXml(ImageUrl);

    System.Xml.XmlNode node = (System.Xml.XmlNode)xmlDoc.DocumentElement;
    System.Xml.XmlElement imageElem = node.SelectSingleNode("@/RF_SearchTermBanners/ImageName") as System.Xml.XmlElement;

    string imgUrl = imageElem.InnerText;

    if (imgUrl != null && imgUrl != string.Empty)
    {
        SearchBanner.ImageUrl = "~/Themes/Default/Images" + imgUrl;
        SearchBanner.Visible = true;
    }
    else
    {
        SearchBanner.ImageUrl = string.Empty;
        SearchBanner.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

Please help.

Comment: The code LoadXml(ImagePath) looks strange. Are you sure you're passing the XML Text to the LoadXml method? It looks like you're passing an Url, but it does not work like that....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you mean `@"/RF_SearchTermBanners/ImageName"`? In XPath, an `@` symbol represents an attribute.

Comment: Well I am new to Xml parsing and I got this from googling. So I changed the previous XPath to "RF_SearchTermBanners/ImageName" and I still get the same error.

Comment: That will look for an element named RF_SearchTermBanners within the element RF_SearchTermBanners. Change the XPath to `ImageName` or `/RF_SearchTermBanners/ImageName` (with a leading `/`).

Comment: That solved the problem. I was being childish on that, it was simple. Thanks.